# How to sort bibliography by languages in bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, languages, sorting

As an absolute newbie in Tex-related stuff, i need your advice.
I'm making an article in online version of Tex - sharelatex.com, so i need to sort the bibliography from .bib-file for my article by the language of sources.
Here i have the code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
Some text \cite{}.
\bibliographystyle{gost780s}
\bibliography{name}
\end{document}
```

The bibtex file looks like:

```
@article{Razumova,
title={Исламский Банкинг: Мировой Опыт и Возможности Для России},
author={Разумова, Ирина Анатольевна},
journal={Учебные Записки Международного Банковского Института},
number={11-1},
pages={157-166},
year={2015},
language="russian",
publisher={Международный Банковский Институт Санкт-Петербург}
}

@book{iqbal2011introduction,
title={An introduction to Islamic finance: Theory and practice},
author={Iqbal, Zamir and Mirakhor, Abbas},
volume={687},
year={2011},
language="English",
publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}

@book{warde2000islamic,
title={Islamic finance in the global economy},
author={Warde, Ibrahim},
year={2011},
language="english",
publisher={Edinburgh University Press}
}

@article{bektax,
title={Исламские налоги как эффективный инструмент решения социально-экономических проблем в местах компактного проживания мусульман в России},
author={Беккин, Р.И},
journal={Проблемы современной экономики},
number={03},
pages={480--490},
year={2009},
language="russian",
publisher={Научно-производственная компания" РОСТ"}
}
```

As a result, i have the properly-formed bibliography, sorted alphabetically, but beginning with the latin letters. So, what i need is to make my bibliography sorted by language, beginning from the cyrillic-russian.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are there any further sorting criteria, e.g., alphabetically by first author's surname within each language group?

Comment: Actually, the gost780s style was sorting everything by Lastnames automatically, but it appeared, that it was wrong "gost-" (damn russian criterias) , so, after i chaged the style, there occured a need for alphabetic lastnames sorting. I would be extremely grateful, if you could help!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your follow-up question. Are you saying that the new bibliography style you're using, `gost-` (?), doesn't perform any sorting? Please advise.

Comment: Well, new bibliography style does put every info about the sources in a right order due to the requirments. But it sorts the sources by their appearence in text. Is it possible to sort them both alphabetically, by languages and keeping on using theutf8gost705u style?

Comment: If I understood your reply correctly, the new bibliography style performs *no sorting at all* -- the order of the entries in the bibliography is the exact order in which they are cited in the body of the document. If this interpretation is correct, i.e., if no sorting by author, year, *or* language is to be performed by BibTeX, it is up to you to structure the citations so that the Russian-language items are cited before the English-language items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BibTeX doesn't provide a lot of fancy tools for sorting bib entries other than by authors'/editors' surnames and publication years. A fallback tool is available, though: the `\noopsort` macro, to be placed at the top of the bib file:

```
@preamble{ "\providecommand\noopsort[1]{}" }
```

Then, change the `author` fields as follows: insert `\noopsort{1}` at that start of the `author` (or, if needed, `editor`) field for the Russian-language entries, and `\noopsort{2}` at that start of the `author` field for the Russian-language entries. (You don't have to choose `1` and `2` -- just choose any two non-special characters that come before the alphabetical characters in the ASCII sequence.)

(The following code and associated screenshot use the `plain` bibliography style, as my TeX distribution doesn't appear to have the `gost780s` style.)

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@preamble{ "\providecommand\noopsort[1]{}" }

@article{Razumova,
title={Исламский Банкинг: Мировой Опыт и Возможности Для России},
author={\noopsort{1}Разумова, Ирина Анатольевна},
journal={Учебные Записки Международного Банковского Института},
number={11-1},
pages={157-166},
year={2015},
language="russian",
publisher={Международный Банковский Институт Санкт-Петербург}
}

@book{iqbal2011introduction,
title={An introduction to Islamic finance: Theory and practice},
author={\noopsort{2}Iqbal, Zamir and Mirakhor, Abbas},
volume={687},
year={2011},
language="English",
publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}

@book{warde2000islamic,
title={Islamic finance in the global economy},
author={\noopsort{2}Warde, Ibrahim},
year={2011},
language="english",
publisher={Edinburgh University Press}
}

@article{bektax,
title={Исламские налоги как эффективный инструмент решения социально-экономических проблем в местах компактного проживания мусульман в России},
author={\noopsort{1}Беккин, Р.И},
journal={Проблемы современной экономики},
number={03},
pages={480--490},
year={2009},
language="russian",
publisher={Научно-производственная компания" РОСТ"}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}  % choose a suitable font package
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```